# How to fix Samsung printer JobAccounting2 module printing crashes?

Tags: macos, crash, printing

There are 2 brand new iMac running Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Both machines have a wired ethernet connection to a wired Samsung CLX-6260ND MFC (multifunction) printer.

Installation is a piece of cake, go to system preferences, printers and scanners, add a new printer, and the printer is already there in the Bonjour list. Now the OS downloads additional software and ready to print.

Then the issues start occurring, before even creating a print preview the applications crashes.

---

### Word JobAccounting2 printing error

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Date/Time: 2015-03-18 10:45:27 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Word
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Word
Application Signature: MSWD
Application Version: 14.4.8.150116
Crashed Module Name: JobAccounting2
Crashed Module Version: 2.14
Crashed Module Offset: 0x00005b06
Blame Module Name: JobAccounting2
Blame Module Version: 2.14
Blame Module Offset: 0x00005b06
...
```

---

### Safari JobAccounting2 printing error

```
PlugIn Path:       /Library/Printers/Samsung/PDEs/JobAccounting2.bundle/Contents/MacOS/JobAccounting2
PlugIn Identifier: com.samsung.driver.print.pde.JobAccounting2
PlugIn Version:    2.14 (2.14)

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000a8
```

---

The faulty JobAccounting2 module is:

```
$ ls -l /Library/Printers/Samsung/PDEs/JobAccounting2.bundle/Contents/MacOS/JobAccounting2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  194320 Oct 31  2013 /Library/Printers/Samsung/PDEs/JobAccounting2.bundle/Contents/MacOS/JobAccounting2
```

The fault printer driver version number according to: System Preferences > Printers and scanners > Printing > Samsung CLX 6260 Series > Open print queue > Settings > General: 1.11.01

[image: System Preferences > Printers and scanners > Printing > Samsung CLX 6260 Series > Open print queue > Settings > General: Driver version: 1.11.01]

Regression:

- Word, Excel, Outlook, Safari, Firefox, they all crash.
- Have installed OS updates, still printing crashes.
- We installed the most recent (09.03.2015 also known as 5.00.0a04) printer driver from Samsung website, and still crashes all over. This driver installation doesn't seem to update the Apple installed Samsung driver: driver version for the already installed printer doesn't change.
- Install the Samsung network printer on a different Mac, running OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks), JobAccounting2 print crashes there too.

How to fix these JobAccounting2 module print crashes?

Comment: Ouch - we're back to Samsung's wonderful Mac support :( I've always found the built-in Apple/Samsung drivers work better than Samsung's own - but they don't necessarily have all the modules.

Comment: @Tetsujin In this case there were only drivers installed that were offered by the operating system. In managed to fix this by removing the old Mac OS X Samsung drivers and installing printer drivers as downloaded from Samsung on the 10.9 Mac. I am going to write an answer soon.

Comment: I have set the printer as "default" and it doesn't crash!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no README or similar file in the Samsung updated printer driver distribution. For the already installed printers the driver won't be updated when installing the updated driver.

The trick is to remove all Samsung printers affected from System Preferences > Printing and scanning > Printing. And then adding those printers again.

Then the Samsung driver version updates, in this case from 1.11.01 to 5.00:

[image]